# Django Restful Framework Update Object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am a Beginner in Django Restful Framework. I want to create a BookAPI, here is my model:

models.py

```
book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
book_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
order = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Now I can get the list of books without order by 
   GET http://localhost:8000/api/books/.

And I want to modify the order of books and let every book has a unique order with PUT http://localhost:8000/api/books/orders

```
"Payload":
{
"books": [
    {
        "book_id": 1,
        "order": 1
    },
    {
        "book_id": 2,
        "order": 2
    }
]
```

}

and the response:

```
"Response":
[
{
    "book_id": 1,
    "order": 1
},
{
    "book_id": 2,
    "order": 2
}
]
```

Here is my serializer.py:

```
class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields=['book_id','order']
```

What should I do for update function in serializer.py?

Here is my view.py

```
class OrderAPIView(APIView):
    #get order and book id
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request, book_id):
        order = order.objects.get(book_id=book_id)
        serializer = OrderSerializer(order, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your plan for how book order should be specified? Should it be a `PUT` or `PATCH` on `/api/books/<book_id>`? Also, can you show your views?

Comment: Hi, I just add my view.py taking from the tutorial. Thank you.